# How do you set a "Document class" from an SWC in Flash CS4?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash-cs4, document, swc

I have an SWC with a class called Content. I want to set it as the "Document Class" in Flash. However, after setting up the SWC in the .fla, I am receiving an error message saying that "A definition for the document class could not be found in the classpath,..." Setting up the direct class folder works fine, but I need to distribute this SWC and do not want to include the sources.

***Is it possible to use a class as the Document Class if it resides in an SWC?***

I've found some links that seem to indicate no, but I need to find out definitively.

http://balazs.sebesteny.com/document-class-from-swc/

forums.adobe.com/thread/452045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't try it myself. But maybe, if linking directly against the swc doesn't work, a possible workaround could be writting a simple do-nothing class that just extends the class in your swc and have your fla use it as the document class.

Something like:

```
package {
    import your.package.Content;

    public class MainClass extends Content {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it does work. I actually already solved it yesterday and hadn't gotten around to updating this post. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

confirmed still broken in cs5, and the subclass workaround also still works. i have informed a flash authoring team engineer at adobe. i am attempting to gain support for a fix to this issue here:

http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000304.html

Comment: Still broken in CS6.  Defeats the whole purpose of using the SWC if I have to define a dummy class (and corresponding AS file) for every one of the hundred of "Lesson" swfs I'm publishing.